# Trouble with loops in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I only want to do a simple loop:

I want something like:

```
loop do
   puts "What hotel would you like to pick"

   hotelCode = gets.chomp.downcase #gets user input and puts it lowerCase 

   if hotelCode != "a" || hotelCode != "b" || hotelCode != "c" || hotelCode != "d"  # if user input is not a,b,c,d break 
       break
   else 
       puts "How many nights would you like to stay"
       nights = gets.chomp.to_i 
   end
end #end while loop

puts "congrats u got out"
```

In my code, it just keeps breaking out of the loop no matter what I do.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You're using `||`. You want `&&`. If it's "a" then it's != "b" so the condition is still true.

Comment: ... lets never speak of this again lol \

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want your loops ends if the input is NONE of those choice. So

```
if hotelCode != "a" && hotelCode != "b" & hotelCode != "c" && hotelCode != "d"
```

better

```
if !["a", "b", "c", "d"].include?(hotelCode)
```

even better

```
if !%w(a b c d).include?(hotelCode)
```

or

```
unless %w(a b c d).include?(hotelCode)
```

Comment: interesting i like the look of the if !%w(a b c d).include?(hotelCode) .. i get its saying if hotelCode does not include  a b c or d . but what is the !%w?

Comment: @sublimeaces: `%w` is a string array literal. Try it in the irb, `%w(a b c d)`

Comment: @sublimeaces more info [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings).

Answer (score 1):

From your code, it should be something like this:

```
loop do
   puts "What hotel would you like to pick"
   hotelCode = gets.chomp.downcase #gets user input and puts it lowerCase 
   if hotelCode != "a" && hotelCode != "b" && hotelCode != "c" && hotelCode != "d"  # if user input is not a,b,c,d break 
       break
   else 
       puts "How many nights would you like to stay"
       nights = gets.chomp.to_i 
   end
end #end while loop
puts "congrats u got out"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if hotelCode != "a" || hotelCode != "b" || ...
```

If hotel code is "b", it will break on the first condition. If it is "a", it will break on the second. This condition is impossible to satisfy.

Either use

```
 if hotelCode != "a" && hotelCode != "b" && ...
```

or

```
 if hotelCode == "a" || hotelCode == "b" || ...
   # handle valid hotel
 else
   break
 end
```

Simple boolean math :) Or better yet, use one of Ursus' examples.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a method of the [String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-delete) class. Here are several, ordered by my personal preference (high to low).

```
hotel_code !~ /[abcd]/

hotel_code =~ /[^abcd]/

!"abcd".include?(hotel_code)

"abcd".index(hotel_code).nil?

hotel_code.count("abcd").zero?

hotel_code.delete("abcd") == hodel_code

"abcd".delete(hotel_code) == "abcd"
```

The second returns an integer ("truthy") or `nil` ("falsy"); the others return `true` or `false`.